# How to save data json from api external to database in laravel

Tags: json, laravel, guzzle

i want to generate reports from api external, using guzzle, here is my result

```
{#430 ▼


+"data": {#427 ▼
    +"report_id": "20190801-5f6e21a5"
    +"status": 5
    +"creation_date": "2019-08-01 13:19:49"
    +"due_date": "2019-08-02 13:19:49"
    +"data": {#432 ▼
      +"chassis_number": "ACR50-0183692"
      +"engine": "2AZFE"
      +"manufacture_date": "2014-07"
      +"registration_date": "2019-04-17"
      +"make": "TOYOTA"
      +"model": "ESTIMA"
      +"displacement": "2360"
      +"fuel": "GASOLINE"
    }
  }
  +"error": ""
}
```

but i dont know how to get the value from this json and save to database. i want to save value from report_id, status, creation date etc

```html
$client = new Client();
        $body = $client->request('GET', 'https://xxxxx/api/v1/get-report', [
        'headers' => [
            'Accept'     => 'application/json',
            'Carvx-User-Uid' => 'xxxxxx', 
            'Carvx-Api-Key' => 'xxxxxx',
            'needSignature' => '0', 
            'raiseExceptions' => '1',
            'isTest' => '0'
        ],
            'query' => [
                'report_id' => $reportId,
                'true'=>'1'
            ]
    ])->getBody();

    $contents = (string) $body;
    $data = json_decode($contents);
   // dd($data);
    
    //to get value from status 

    $var_status =  var_export($data['status'],true);
    $status = substr($var_status, 1, -1); 
    echo $status;
```

and i get this error

**Cannot use object of type stdClass as array**

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode` by default returns a `Stdclass` object, with properties representing the keys in the json object.

You can tell `json_decode` to return an associative array instead by passing `true` as the second param:

```php
json_decode($contents, true); // returns array
```

Docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: how to echo for STATUS value only?

$var_status =  var_export($data['status'],true);
    $status = substr($var_status, 1, -1); 
    echo $status;

still error